# How to query a database from my rails app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

**:: I want to query my db, save the results in a variable and display those results in the view by that variable. I don't know how to display or save the results.**

**What's the proper way to execute this?**

Here's the code:

This is the form (first page):

```
                                # submit: A controller | shoot: A method
<%= simple_form_for :computer , url:submit_shoot_path , :method => :get  do |f| %>

        <%= f.input :used_at, collection: ["Home" , "Work" , "Travel"] , wrapper_html: { class: 'col-xs-3'} %>
        <%= f.input :used_for, collection: [ "Programming", "Gaming", "Blogging"], wrapper_html: { class: 'col-xs-3'} %>
        <br/>
        <%= f.input :cash, input_html: { max: 500 } , wrapper_html: { class: 'col-xs-3' } %>
        <br/>
        <%= f.button :submit, value: 'Submit' , :name => nil %>
    <% end %>
```

Here's my model:

```
   # MODEL
class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :name
  has_one :used_at
  has_one :used_for
  has_one :cash
end
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    class SubmitController < ApplicationController
   def shoot
   used_at = params[:where_at]
  used_for = params[:used_at]
  cash = params[:amount]
   #I tried to store the variable.
  #Is this correct? v
  search = Computer.find(8)
  render:shoot
  end
  end
```

VIEW:
I want to list all the rows that was affected by the query.(Ex: find * computers where price ='400')
And the results will be something like this:

Name: Toshiba(name) | Price: $1.00(cash) | Home(used_at) | Programming(used_for).

**This page displays with no errors. It loads but how do I load the query results?**
Results (Second page):shoot.html.erb

** Now inside the view I want to list the results from the db query in a list(li) **

```
    <html>
<head>Hello</head>

<body>
<table>
  <ul>
      <!-- Isn't there a search.each do |t| method that goes here. -->
  </ul>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, I ask you, SOF rubyist's help me solve this.

NOTE: Please no recommendations to guides.rubyonrails.org.

Answer (score 0):

In your SubmitController.rb

```
@search = Computer.find(8)  ## @search is a instance variable now. You can use it in views. @Search contains a record from computer whose id is 8.
```

Then in View file,

```
<%= @search.name  %>  ## i assume name is a column in computers method.
<%= @search.xyz %> ## xyz is again a column name and so on...
```

If you write in SubmitControoler.rb

```
 @search = Computer.all  ## fetch all the records from computers tables.
```

then it will fetch collection of objects of Computer class. You can iterate in view like below:

```
 <% @search.each do |x| %>
   <%= x.name %>
   <%= x.xyz %>
     ......
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I received an error: " undefined method `each' ". How do I fix this?

Comment: Share the code for controller method and respected view.

Comment: I fixed it. I changed @ search to @ computers (plural). and In the model 'Computer' I changed the used_at , where_at's to UsedAt and WhereAt.

Comment: You made a mistake in defining association in model. Association names are in camel case. In controller,  @ search or @ computers doesn't make any difference. What instance variable you take in controller method, you need to use it in appropriate view.